# Const-ness affecting concurrent algorithms?

Tags: c++, concurrency, parallel-processing, const-correctness, data-race

Are there any examples of the absence or presence of `const` affecting the concurrency of any C++ Standard Library algorithms or containers?  If there aren't, is there any reason using the `const`-ness in this way is not permitted?

To clarify, I'm assuming concurrent `const` access to objects is data-race free, as advocated in several places, including [GotW 6](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/24/gotw-6a-const-correctness-part-1-3/).

By analogy, the `noexcept`-ness of move operations can affect the performance of `std::vector`s methods such as [`resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept#Notes).

I skimmed through several of the C++17 concurrent Algorithms, hoping to find an example, but I didn't find anything.  Algorithms like [`transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) *don't* require the `unary_op` or `binary_op` function objects to be `const`.  I did find [`for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) takes a `MoveConstructible` function object for the original, non execution policy version, and take a `CopyConstructible` function object for the C++17 execution policy version; I thought this might be an example where the programmer was manually forced to select one or the other based on if the function object could be safely copied (a `const` operation)... but at the moment I suspect this requirement is just there to support the return type (`UnaryFunction` vs. `void`).

Comment: Concurrent read-only acces to objects are always race-free regardless of `const` or not.

Comment: @super Calls to non-const `F::operator()` may not be data race free.

Comment: Your point being? Calls to const `F::operator()` can also contain data races. A `const` method is allowed to modify `mutable` members of the class. Those facts doesn't change the fact that read-only access is always race free.

Comment: @super As stated in GotW6: "Concurrent `const` operations on the same object are required to be safe without the calling code doing external synchronization." It goes on to address `mutable` state, sometimes for caching results, and always for multi-thread safe synchronization primitives (`atomic`, `mutable`).

Comment: Your point still remains a mystery. Good luck with your question.

Comment: @super Imagine a parallel `for_each` algorithm that: if `F::operator() const` is available it uses the input `f` object concurrently in each thread, else it makes a copy of `f` for each thread so that it can safely call `F::operator() /*non-const*/`.  This would save copy constructor calls.  (Of course, this isn't the only performance factor in this scenario: sharing one instance between threads may introduce some contention, for example.)

Comment: Related video: [H.Sutter. You don’t know `const` and `mutable`](https://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-You-dont-know-blank-and-blank)